# Can't See Info (Metadata) in Prawn Generated PDF's

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I am using the `prawn` Ruby gem to generate PDF files in my application. I would like to insert some metadata in the PDF and have done as specified in the docs:

```
  private def prawn_create_document(pdf_filespec, report_text, doc_short_name)
    metadata = {
        RBCreator:      "RockBooks v#{VERSION} (#{PROJECT_URL})",
        RBCreated:      Time.now.to_s,
        RBDocumentCode: doc_short_name.to_s,
    }

    Prawn::Document.generate(pdf_filespec, info: metadata) do
    ...
```

However, I do not see this metadata in the generated PDF. I've used `pdfinfo` and `okular` on Linux with KDE (Kubuntu 20.04) and `Preview` on Mac OS.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the PDF generation, it's with the tools used to view the generated PDF.

The following tools can be used to successfully display the custom metadata:

- `exiftool` (install with `sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl` on Ubuntu-based Linux)
- Apache Tika (Java library), accessible in JRuby using the `rika` gem (see https://github.com/keithrbennett/rika). Here is a script that can be used to display metadata from files of many different types:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby

# You will probably want to disable warnings by adding `2>/dev/null` to your command, as in:
# view-metadata my.pdf 2>/dev/null

require 'rika'
require 'amazing_print'

raise 'Syntax is view-metadata filespec' if ARGV.empty?
filespec = ARGV.first
puts "Metadata for file #{filespec}:\n\n"
ap Rika.parse_metadata(filespec)
```

Output for my file included:

```
                                  "RBDocumentCode" => "balance_sheet",
               "pdf:docinfo:custom:RBDocumentCode" => "balance_sheet",
                                      "RBCreated" => "2021-01-03 17:03:50 -0500",
                                      "RBCreator" => "RockBooks v0.7.1 (https://github.com/keithrbennett/rock_books)",
                   "pdf:docinfo:custom:RBCreator" => "RockBooks v0.7.1 (https://github.com/keithrbennett/rock_books)",
                   "pdf:docinfo:custom:RBCreated" => "2021-01-03 17:03:50 -0500",
```

I don't know why these were created in the two forms (not prefixed, and prefixed with `pdf:docinfo:custom:`).